# Comportamento anormal de Iterador dentro de uma funcao JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Eu tenho uma funcao de gerar os botoes da paginacao dinamicamente, entao eu tenho que gerar um botao para cada pagina ( do total de pagina ), entao eu usei um `for` para isso.

```
$('#resultadoBusca').append('<ul id="resultPaginacao" onClick="buscar()" class="pagination justify-content-center">');
for(i=0; i < result['total_paginas']; i++){
    $('#resultPaginacao').append(`<li value=${i+1} class="page-item"><a class="page-link">${i+1}</a></li>`);
}
$('#resultPaginacao').append('</ul>');
```

O que é estranho, é que quando eu dou um `$('#resultPaginacao li').val()` para pegar o valor, sempre é me retornado 1, por algum motivo o iterador que poe o valor em `value` nao está sendo incrementado, mas para colocar o numero do item, está. Ele imprime os botoes certinhos, 1,2,3,4...

O meu objetivo é, quando for clicado em um desses botoes da paginacao, a funcao `buscar()` seja chamada, e ela deve pegar o valor do botao que foi clicado. Alguem tem uma ideia de como fazer isso, sem mudar muito o formato do codigo ?

[image: Texto da paginacao]

Pensei em tentar pegar o valor assim: `$('#resultPaginacao li').text()` mas isso sempre me retorna o valor de `123456`

EDIT:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Value esta sendo atribuido corretamente, parece que o problema esta na captura desse value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, resolvi da seguinte forma

```
$('#resultadoBusca').append('<ul id="resultPaginacao" class="pagination justify-content-center">');
for(i=0; i < result['total_paginas']; i++){
    $('#resultPaginacao').append(`<li onClick="buscar(${i+1})" class="page-item"><a class="page-link">${i+1}</a></li>`);
}
$('#resultPaginacao').append('</ul>');
```

Basicamente passei o valor da pagina para a funcao de busca, dessa forma, nao preciso me preocupar em capturar o valor com Jquery..